# How to properly navigate directory paths in C++

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio, path, c++17

I'm working on a solution within Visual Studio. It currently has two projects.

I will represent Directories or folders with capitals letters, and filenames will be all lower case. My solution structure is as follows:

- SolutionDir

  - ProjectLib

    - source files
    - Shaders

      - shader files
  - ProjectApp

    - source files
  - x64

    - Debug

      - app.exe // debug build
    - Release

      - app.exe // release build

Within `ProjectLib` I have a function to open and read my Shader files. Here is what my function looks like:

```
std::vector<char> VRXShader::readFile(std::string_view shadername) {
    std::string filename = std::string("Shaders/");
    filename.append(shadername);

    std::ifstream file(filename.data(), std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);

    if (!file.is_open()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to open file!");
    }

    size_t fileSize = static_cast<size_t>(file.tellg());
    std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);

    file.seekg(0);
    file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);
    
    file.close();

    return buffer;       
}
```

This function is being called within my `VRXDevices::createPipeline` function and here is the relevant code:

```
void VRXDevices::createPipeline(
    VkDevice device, VkExtent2D swapChainExtent, VkRenderPass renderPass, 
    const std::vector<std::string_view>& shaderNames, 
    VkPipelineLayout& pipelineLayout, VkPipeline& pipeline
) {
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> shaderCodes;
    shaderCodes.resize(shaderNames.size());

    for (auto& name : shaderNames) {
        auto shaderCode = VRXShader::readFile(name.data());
    }

    // .... more code
}
```

The names are being created and passed to this function from my `VRXEngine::initVulkan` function which can be seen here:

```
void VRXEngine::initVulkan(
    std::string_view app_name, std::string_view engine_name, 
    glm::ivec3 app_version, glm::ivec3 engine_version
) {
    //... code

    std::vector<std::string_view> shaderFilenames{ "vert.spv", "frag.spv" };
    VRXDevices::createPipeline(device_, swapChainExtent_, renderPass_, shaderFilenames, pipelineLayout_, graphicsPipeline_);
    
}
```

I'm using just the name of the shader files such as `vert.spv`, `frag.spv`, `geom.spv` etc. I'm not including the paths here because these will be used as the key to a `std::map<string_view, object>`. So I'm passing a vector of these names from my `::initVulkan` function into `::createPipeline()`.

Within `::createPipeline()` is where `::readFile()` is being called passing in the `string_view`.

Now as for my question... within `::readFile()` I'm creating a local `string` and trying to initialize it with the appropriate path... then append to it the `string_view` for the shader's filename as can be seen from these two lines...

```
std::string filename = std::string("Shaders/");
filename.append(shadername);
```

I'm trying to figure out the appropriate string to initialize `filename` with... `Shaders/` will be a part of the name, but it's not finding the file and I'm not sure what the appropriate prefix should be...

My working directories within both projects are as follows:

- ProjectApp -> $(SolutionDir)x64/Release AND $(SolutionDir)x64/Debug
- ProjectLib -> $(SolutionDir)x64/Release AND $(SolutionDir)x64/Debug

So I need to go back 2 directories then into `VRX Engine/Shader`...

What is the correct string value for navigating back directories?

Would I initialize `filename` with `"../../VRX Engine/Shaders/"` or is it `"././"` also, should I have quotes around `VRX Engine` since there is a space in the folder name? What do I need to initialize `filename` with before I append the `shader name` to it?

Comment: It took me a bunch of trials and errors... but I ended up being able to open the files initializing `filename` with `../../VRX Engine/Shaders/`. The issue that was causing it to fail, had to do with the settings of my `LibProject` or the `VRX Engine` project which is being built as a static library. Within my `Application` which is being built as an executable, I had the appropriate `working path` directories in which I described above. I had forgotten to update or modify the `LibProject`'s working directory to the same... That's why it wasn't working and wasn't finding or opening the files!

Answer (score 1):

> How to properly navigate directory paths in C++

### It depends on which C++ standard your implementation claims to be compliant with.

### Or else which additional libraries can you use.

C++ is useful on computers *without* directories (e.g. *inside* some operating system kernel coded in C++ and compiled with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) for examples).

#### Look on [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) for details.

Licensing constraints could matter when using extra [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source) libraries.

If your implementation is C++17 compliant (in a "hosted" not "freestanding" way), use the [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) part of the standard library.

If your operating system supports the [Qt](https://qt.io/) or [POCO](https://pocoproject.org/) frameworks and you are allowed to use them (e.g. on C++11), you could use appropriate APIs. So [`QDir`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html) and related classes with Qt, [`Poco::Path`](https://pocoproject.org/slides/080-Files.pdf) and related classes with POCO.

Perhaps you want to code just for the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API). Then read [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/) (I never coded on Windows myself, just on POSIX or Unix -e.g. Linux- and MSDOS....).

Comment: I appreciate your feedback. I do understand that `std::filesystem` is available and a part of the C++17 standard, however, that wasn't the focus of my question. It was referring exactly to the proper character sequence or `string` to navigate through folders or directories. I'm in the process of getting my functions to work and I'm building it and testing it on a Windows machine using Visual Studio. Once I get the framework and boilerplate code of `Vulkan` working to render a simple triangle, I can then go back and refactor it making it portable in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Also, I haven't really had a need to use `std::filesystem` so I would have to create a few test projects to get used to its interface and internal workings.

Answer (score 0):

I was originally initializing my local temp `string` properly with `"../../VRX Engine/Shaders/"` before appending the `string_view` to it to be able to open the file. This was actually correct, but because it didn't initially work, I was assuming that it was wrong.

The correct string value for going back one directory should be `"../"` at least on `Windows`, I'm not sure about `Linux`, `Mac`, `Android`, etc...

My problem wasn't with the string at all, it pertained to settings within my projects. Within my project that builds into an executable, I had its working directory set to `$(SolutionDir)x64/Debug` and `$(SolutionDir)x64/Release` respectively which is correct for my solutions structure.

The issue was within my `Engine` project that is being built as a static library. Within its settings for its working directory, I had forgotten to modify both of the `Debug` and `Release` build options... These were still set to the default values of Visual Studio which I believe is `(ProjectDir)`. Once I changed these to `$(SolutionDir)x64/Debug` and `$(SolutionDir)x64/Release` to match that of my `ApplicationProject`, I was able to open and read the contents of the files.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @BarrnetChou I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer!